# Nifi ExecuteScript with Groovy: OOM exception

Tags: java, groovy, apache-nifi

I am using an ExecuteScript processor in NiFi to execute a PUT command with the flowfile I have specified. However, right now I am getting an OutOfMemory exception when the file is greater than 2GB. My memory settings on NiFi are much higher. I've also seen much larger flow files work with some of the other provided Nifi processor.

I cannot use InvokeHTTP as I have 2 different return codes with conflicting relationships that I need to handle.

Currently my JVM settings for NiFi are

```
java.arg.2=-Xms16g
java.arg.3=-Xmx32g
```

Here is a snippet of how the data is getting PUT.

```
    InputStream i = session.read(flowFile)
    def baseUrl = new URL(Location)
    def connection = baseUrl.openConnection()
    connection.setDoOutput(true)
    connection.setRequestMethod('PUT')
    connection.connect()

    OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream()
    os << i
    i.close()

    os.flush()
    os.close()
```

Is there a setting for groovy in NiFi that needs to be set to increase this memory limit? Currently running NiFi 1.9.2

Comment: what processor you are using that fails with OOM? could you share full stacktrace?

Comment: My guess is that either/neither the InputStream nor OutputStream is buffered, so it may be reading the whole file into memory, or spooling it into memory before writing it out. You may need to use buffered streams and/or copy the content "block by block"

Comment: I updated with a buffer, but I am still encountering the same issue with varying files over 2GB

Comment: to avoid guessing please share the full stacktrace from log file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was solved using an inputstream read buffer AND adding ChunkedStreamingMode

```
connection.setChunkedStreamingMode(1024)
```

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int len;
while ((len = i.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    os.write(buffer, 0, len);
    os.flush;
}
```